# Fourier transformation of an Image in R

Tags: r, image-processing

I am using the package imager to transform a set of images to fourier space:

```
library(imager)
face2 <- load.image(path)
FFT(face2)
```

Unfortunately, I obtain this error

```
Error in FFT_realim(im.real, inverse = inverse) : 
cimg::stderr(): Reference to 'stderr' stream not allowed in R mode ('cimg_use_r' is defined).
```

Even if I try with one of the images that comes with the package, it still doesn't work

```
FFT(boats)
```

Although the error here is slightly different:

```
Error in FFT_realim(im.real, inverse = inverse) : 
      CImgList<double>::FFT(): Specified real and imaginary parts (256,384,1,3) have non 2^N dimension along the Y-axis.
```

I have no idea of what is going on, so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: FFT(boats) work for me... I am on R 3.6.1. You want to clear your environment first and retry?

Comment: I tried that and nothing. I am also on R 3.6.1...